# How to create session with user sreen resolution on his first site visit with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, session-variables

I am trying to create session with user's screen resolution when he enters the website with ajax but it doesn't work. I am passing to the php file the screen resolution and php creates the session but it is not accessible on the first page load, but after he refesh the website.. How to make it work without js window.location because I do not want the page to load twice..neither to redirect user to other page.. So far I have this:

```
function res(){
var w = screen.width;
$.post('./ajax/resolution.php?&w='+w);
}    

<body onload="res();">
```

and the php code in resolution.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(is_numeric($_REQUEST['w'])){
$resolution=$_REQUEST['w'];
}else $resolution='1240';
$_SESSION['r']=$resolution;
?>
```

How to have $_SESSION['r'] ready for use on first visitor's page load?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think cookies would be a better solution for what you're looking. In the first page you create the cookie in javascript:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
document.cookie ="width='" + w + "';"+expires+";path=/";
```

and later you can get it in php like this:

```
$_COOKIE['w']
```

Comment: lose the `&` before the `w`

Comment: what you think losing & will change? I am not having a problem reading post or get - the problem is that the session becomes visible on second page load.. which probably means that body onload is late for generating the session?

Comment: oh sorry i did not read your question correctly, i thought you were having problems with the variables. I don't know if you can do what you are looking, because you are using client and server.. have you tried using cookies?

Comment: no, did not try with cookies. What would be the difference? I mean how to pass the cookie to the php before page loads?

Comment: the question would be why do you want to save the width? i think i could be easier with cookies because you could create the cookie without using ajax having it ready to use in the same page and if you want to use it later in your php

Comment: rod_torres - this is good point, but cookie is still available after first page load !

Comment: rod_torres I saw your edit but I am telling you - cookies and sessions are not accessible on first page load - did you tested it?

Comment: Like i said, you should tell what do you want to do with the width. If you want to use it in the first page you could just use the javascript variable

Comment: rod_torres I want to get the screen resolution and restyle the html and also add query limits for different resolutions. I don't know a way to get the js variable and use it in php that's why I tried workaround using ajax to pass it to the php.. how else you can pass the value from: var w = screen.width;
to php?

Comment: rod, thank you for your help ! I am going to sleep.. no clear solution anyways ! thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when you are loading page for the first time session is set but you need to change you HTML after that, otherwise it will stay same as it was before setting session variable, to change that you have to do something you want in success function in you `$.post`  call

for example

```
$.post( "'./ajax/resolution.php?&w='+w", function( data ) {
   $(body).append(data); //or whatever you want
});
```

but also you have to output something from your php file

```
.
.
$_SESSION['r']=$resolution;
echo $_SESSION['r'];
?>
```

Comment: Something like what Jerko, can you provide a sample please? What will success do - hope not to reload the page?

Comment: and yeah you should change `$.post` for `$.get` and you don't need that `&` as others mentioned

Comment: Looks like there is no solution that doesn't waste system resources for this simple task..

Answer (score 0):

With an ajax login, you can do something like the following. On your login page include a body onload or document.ready function as follows:

```
<body onload="ajaxScreenRes()">
```

where the onload function is defined as:

```
function ajaxScreenRes() {
    var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
    var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
    var ajaxRequest;

    //Your ajax method, then 

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ScreenResFile.php?Height=" + screenHeight + "&width=" + 
    screenWidth, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);        

}
```

Your file ScreenResFile.php then stores the screenHeight/Width in the appropriate table. Then, when user logs in, you can echo the height and width where needed...I used a div as an example:

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$sql = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT height, width, etc. FROM 
logintable WHERE user = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_SESSION['user']."'"));


?>


//lots of html then

<div style="height:<?php echo $sql['height'] ?>; width:<?php echo $sql['height'] ?>;">

</div>
```

Comment: The One and Only ChemistryBlob - I don't want to involve mysql for this !